# Modbus c terminal

Tags: modbus

I have to communicate with a device. There are A,B,C Terminals.

A and B are standard. But What is The C Terminal? Is it ground?

Comment: It's the rocket launch signal. Seriously, do you think we are clairvoyants here?

Comment: Which device? Name? Brand? Model? Try measuring resistance from C to device ground or chassis.

Comment: The A and B terms were already enough of stupid signal names... so I'd ask whoever invented C what they were smoking. Instead, give the signals _rational_ names. Tx+, Tx-, Rx+, Rx-, GND, Shield comes to mind.

Comment: Modbus specifies a protocol. You didn't even mention what kind of physical connection you are using, but as Andy pointed out its probably RS485.

Comment: @Lundin: Actually more like D+,D- and GND would be appropriate for a 3 wire RS485. At least USB got it right.

Comment: @Rev1.0 That is, if it is RS485 and not RS422. We can't know... because they gave the signals retarded names.

Comment: @Lundin: Indeed. That's reminds of annoying large scope variables named "myVar" or "cnt". "cnt" of what dammit?!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because JJJJJJJJJJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"C" is usually ground in RS485 configurations that need ground: -

[image]

And, given that MODBUS uses (or can use) RS485: -

[image]

I suspect "C" means ground for MODBUS too. I don't think the "C" designator is used in MODBUS TCP.

Answer (score 0):

In this context C means Common. It is to limit the common mode voltage if the interfaces are not grounded.

Comment: If I found a terminal connector on some PLC called nothing but "C", I'd be very careful about making such assumptions.